Can't boot into Fedora KDE with USB
I am having a problem booting into Fedora with my USB. When I plug the burned USB in and turn on my computer, it goes "attempting to boot from usb device", then goes, "attempting to boot from optical optical drive", and finally goes "attempting to boot from hard drive".
Now, I am no expert when it comes to desktops, but based on my research so far, it looks like the BIOS is ignoring the USB / not being able to boot in it and then automatically tries to boot into the optical drive, but is unable to (That is fine), and finally tries booting into the hard drive, which, of course means, booting into my current OS, linux mint. I think this is normal and is happening based on the boot order set in BIOS, which is USB Device -> Optical Drive -> Hard Drive. It just fails booting from USB device for some reason which is why it tries the other two options.
What I want to know are the potential reasons this is failing and what I can do to fix it.
Here is some info that might be useful in helping me,
My computer's hardware:

1 TB of storage. One hard drive.
16 GBs of ram.
NVIDIA GeForce GT 630.
Intel Xeon E5630 (16 cores).
Computer brand: HP Z600 Workstation.

BIOS type: I don't have UEFI/GPT, whatever that is. It's the legacy BIOS and I wasn't able to find any option for disabling "secure boot" like some other sites were suggesting. I think there is no such thing as secure boot in the legacy BIOS and it's as such, disabled by default. Correct/help me if I am wrong.
Current software:

Linux Mint Virginia 21.3 x86_64: Installed previously via the same USB by burning it and then booting in and initially running alongside windows. But then I simply deleted the windows partition and extended the size of the linux mint partition because I didn't need windows anymore.
Linux Kernel: 5.15.0-116-generic.
NVIDIA driver: 390.

Current partitions in the 1 TB hard disk:

Filesystem Partition 6 820 GB Ext4.

Filesystem Partition 5 538 MB FAT (32-bit version).

Filesystem Partition 7 180 GB Ext4.


Current partitions in the 31 GB USB drive:

Fedora-KDE-Live-40-1-14 Partition 1: ISO9660 2.6 GB ISO9660.

ANACONDA Partition 2 13 MB FAT (16-bit version) EFI SYSTEM.

Partition 3 307 KB.

Free space 29 GB UNALLOCATED.


Here's what I remember I have currently tried:

I initially tried to burn the flagship fedora gnome iso into the USB. I used etcher, linux mint's native usb image writer program, and fedora's media writer to burn it into the USB and boot but no change.

I then changed my mind and decided to go with the KDE image due to some things I read about its performance and intuitiveness online. I used all the 3 programs I mentioned to burn the image into the USB just in case the program I was using was not the right one, and rebooted after each burn, to no avail.

I ran the same Fedora KDE image inside a QEMU VM (Using the program, "Virtual Machine Manager) and it worked completely fine.

Tried finding a secure boot setting in my BIOS, found nothing like it. Looked within every single section that was available, and looked 4 times in the "Security" section.

Checked the ports of my USB and tried booting with both, USB 3, and USB 2.


Been at this for a few days now but nothing works.

Also, side note: I asked this on r/Fedora in Reddit as well but I got no answers there and the post is way below in the feed now. So I figured I won't be getting much from it now and asked it here instead.

Okay, so after trying all the things I mentioned in my question and a bunch of other things that all did not work, I was almost giving up before I just decided to try a list of other software to write to my USB just in case it was a software problem.
And so, after going through a bunch more, I went through unetbootin and to my absolute shock, it actually worked. I am typing this answer from my Fedora KDE installation now. I don't know what unetbootin does different from etcher, fedora media writer, etc., but whatever it is, made it work somehow.
I am accepting this answer for now as it simply works, but I think this post will not be much useful until someone posts an answer that explains why this happened so that people in the future can get help from it. I am ready to accept another answer if it elaborates on this problem and solution.
